# MS Access performance issue?

Tags: performance, ms-access

I have two tables - one has 37,900 rows, the other has 36,022. Each has 12 columns though not all are full, but many are. I am running a simple query to find unmatched records between the two. The query is hanging, or appears to be taking indefinitely long, I hear my processor buzzing continuously. I tried to run the query using very few lines in each table and it worked fine. In your opinion, do you think the tables are just too large and it's normal to have such performance issues when performing such a task?

I first created a query based on each table that appends a reference identifier at the end. These queries work fine. Then I run a query on the two above queries to find unmatched using the reference field.

MS Access 2013 on Windows 8 running on my local machine.

Comment: that would depend on how you've written the query (obviously). And to some extent how powerful your machine is

Comment: I've used the Query Wizard "Find Unmatched Query Wizard". I'm using a work laptop and they tend to be fairly new, though that's not saying much

Comment: Assuming you only matching on one column, then ensure that the columns have an index. Such a small tables should run in less than one second of time – even on a rather weak machine.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - that worked perfectly, I was beginning to lose faith in Access, just migrating from Excel. If you'd like to post it as an answer, then I'd like to mark it as such